# QGIS 3 Pin Multi-part lables

Tags: qgis-3

If I have a multi-part polygon layer and apply labels with every part of multi-part features and then try to place those labels, they all get placed in the same location.

How can I place each duplicated label for each multi-part feature separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, tuns out because the label field had duplicate labels, you will need a unique Id field to attach the axillary label positions to. So I created a new virtual field with the $Id formula to expose the internal id and then attached the labels to this field. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

From `Labels` > `Rendering` tab, select **Label every part of multi-part features** option under the `Feature options`.

[image]

Comment: This only works when you label automatically, as soon as you move the labels of a multipart object all the labels go to one position due to the axillary storage location of the labels!